# Converting list of objects to a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**UPDATE: It was a programming error, please don't post answers. This question will be deleted. If you've already posted an answer please delete**

I'm trying submit a form using jQuery and ajax. One of the fields is a list of objects, like this:

```
data = [{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

I usually use JSON.stringify(data) but that didn't work this time, the server gets `[object Object],[object Object]`

When I do `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` it works but something is changing it back to objects. 
I'm using the jQuery [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and appending this data to the data attribute of the options object:

```
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
        return true; //does nothing
    }

    var options = {
        beforeSubmit:   showRequest,
        url:    '/search.php',
        iframe: true,
        iframeTarget: '#iframe',
        type: 'post'
    };

    options.data.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

How do I convert this to a JSON string that I can send it to the server?

Comment: Same here. Are you working in any special environment?

Comment: can you only post all option setting code ?

Comment: @Umesh i've updated it. There is a beforeSubmit callback that does nothing

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using jQuery and without using JSON libray.

example using php on back-end

```
var data = [{"id":1},{"id":2}];
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'test.php',
    data: {my_array:data},
    success : function(data){
       //alert(data);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       //alert("error");
    }
});
```

in php

```
$my_array= $_REQUEST['my_array'];
print_r($my_array);
```

it will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```